# CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed in magento site

Tags: magento

I tried to install "Delhivery_Lastmile-0.3.0 rar extension" through magento connect manager

but i got following error :

CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed.

Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel.

I am not familiar with ssh, is there any solution for this without using ssh commands.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on linux system you can run following command to add community

```
./mage channel-add http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
```

and if you are on windows pc download mage.bat first from this [link](http://lotusbreath.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/mage.zip)
than run following command

```
mage.bat channel-add http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
```